# Why is the critical seperation distance between two plates for capillary condenstation to occur negative?

Tags: water, capillary-action, condensation

I am currently reading this paper: Auto-adhesion model for MEMS
surfaces taking into account the
effect of surface roughness

Can be found here: https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/4175/0000/Auto-adhesion-model-for-MEMS-surfaces-taking-into-account-the/10.1117/12.395617.short?SSO=1

In their numeric example, they find a critical distance for capillary condensation to occur as being -3.5nm. Why negative ?

Here is the extract from the paper:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I know that log(0.5) is −log(2), hence negative, but I am rather interested in the physical meaning of this ?  **There is no negative distance between two plates !**  So... what does this mean ? Is it maybe measured in a inverted reference  ??

Comment: because $\log(0.5)=-\log(2)$... but something tells me you want a physical not mathematical explanation.

Comment: @nluigi Yes, exactley. My question was maybe not clear. I have updated it.